# Forbidden You don't have permission to access at Bitnami Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, bitnami

I am having a Forbidden Page (You don't have permission to access / on this server) on [my site](http://rocksuper.bitnamiapp.com/). I have modified the owner to root but still it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but I already have a rw-rw-r-- permission, was that not enough?

Comment: That won't be sufficient if those permissions are on a directory, as your web server will also need `x` permission. Also, your web server may have been configured to provide access to only certain IP ranges or reverse-lookups or time-of-day or SSL client certificates or any number of other potential reasons why access is being denied.

Comment: This probably belongs on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1.$ cd $YOUR_RAILS_FOLDER
2.$ chmod 775 -R . 
3.$ touch tmp/restart.txt  ( or other command to restart your rails app)
```

also you need to make sure your rails server has the permission to read all the parent folders.

Comment: Woah, that's almost definitely going to make *far* too many things have the execute permission than need to.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How do I make sure that my rails server has the permission to readd all the parent folders?,..

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the Apache user has permissions in that directory. In the case of BitNami this user is daemon. Also usually you need to add a Directory directive in apache configuration file for that folder. In any case, always check the apache log files, they will likely provide more details about the error.